# VBA Excel: Modifying Existing Graph (Errors)

Tags: vba, excel

Using a macro, I want to modify the data series of a graph at any given time. Whenever I run the macro, I get an error. "error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method"". My code is attached below. Thanks.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim objChrt As ChartObject
Dim chrt As Chart

Set objChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
Set chrt = objChart.Chart

With objChart

    .SetSourceData (ActiveSheet.Range("D2", Cells(2, N + 3))) '"N" is a user defined range

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: the `Cells` method returns a range object which will expectedly raise an error here. What value is `N`?  Also, by putting parentheses around the `ActiveSheet.Range...` could be another source of error. Remove the parentheses.

Comment: @DavidZemens man you are always to the rescue! I love it! Anyway. N can be set to any value. It represents how far down a row are cells active. The "+3" value is simply an offset to start the sequence not at (1,1). Removing the parenthesis didn't help.

Comment: OK, wanted to make sure it was not a true *range* , but rather a `Name` that stores a value.

Comment: Exactly. The syntax for N is `N = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter value", Type:=1)`

Comment: got it, and answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three layers to this problem, I think.

1) `Cells` returns a range object, not a range *address*. When using this as an argument in a `Range` then you need to ensure that either the returned cell *contains a valid address string*, or that you refer directly to the `.Address` of that cell.

It's rare that you'd do the former, but I've seen it done before so I mention it just in case.

2) Parentheses force evaluation, so this line (even as corrected):

```
.SetSourceData (ActiveSheet.Range("D2", Cells(2, N + 3).Address))
```

Is functionally equivalent to:

```
.SetSourceData (ActiveSheet.Range("D2", Cells(2, N + 3).Address)).Value
```

Which probably raises an error because of the parentheses, since I believe the `.SetSourceData` requires a range address, so try:

```
.SetSourceData ActiveSheet.Range("D2", Cells(2, N + 3).Address)
```

And further:

3) The `SetSourceData` is a member of the `Chart` object, not the `ChartObject` object. Confusing, right?

```
with chrt
    .SetSourceData ActiveSheet.Range("D2", Cells(2, N + 3).Address)
End With
```

Comment: The 2nd suggestion didn't work...I'll keep poking around

Comment: What second suggestion? I only have one suggestion in my answer.

Comment: Sorry I meant the last line you have there

Comment: This one? `.SetSourceData ActiveSheet.Range("D2", Cells(2, N + 3).Address)`

Comment: I observe that the variable `N` does NOT exist, although I don't think that should matter, since `Cells(2, 0 + 3).Address` --> `"$C$2"`  If you try a literal assignment, like `SetSourceData Range("D2:G2")` does that also fail? It does not fail when I test it.

Comment: hmmm looking back, instead of `with objChart` do `with chrt`.  The `SetSourceData` is a member of the `Chart` object, not the `ChartObject` object :)

Comment: I just tried a literal assignment and it didn't work. Same error. Is it a syntax error somehow?

Comment: no, the dot is necessary because you're using a `With` object block.  But you're using the wrong object :) See revision.